# What is the fast and reliable way to monitor a java process?

Tags: java, process, monitor

I have a process that will create a java process in another jvm. They stay on the same machine.

My understanding is in the case that two processes run on different machines, generally it can be done through failure detector. But at the moment it is just to spawn another process (Using Runtime.getRuntime()) and pass necessary arguments to the child process. What I can think of is to execute system command e.g. `jps ...` or `ps -ef | grep ...` What would be a better to 
detect if a java process crashes which locates on the same machine with the process that monitor it?

Answer (score 0):

The `Runtime.exec` methods return a `Process`. You have some control over the process through this instance: you can kill it (`destroy`), wait for its termination (`waitFor`) and get its error code once terminated (`exitValue`).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, the Process object may work.

If you want more information, I suggest opening a socket connection between them.  This way you can get more detailed status at any time.

I've done this before and it can be done with a couple incredibly small classes.  Just send and receive lines of text on both ends.

Comment: I have also used the open socket technique for same-machine IPC monitoring, but you don't necessarily need to send or receive any data through the connection. If the process dies then the TCP/IP stack on the host OS will terminate any and all connections the process had open, giving you a fast notification of the peer's failure. Of course if you want status about the process while it's running then a send/recv can be used there for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a script running on the box that monitors the pid and if it crashes signals the parent process to start up a new child process.  Either through a signal or through a listening pipe/local socket.